# On $SUBEXP$, $PP$ and $P/poly$

Tags: complexity-theory, oracle-machines

Complexity zoo https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:D#dtime states $DTIME(f(n))$ with $PP$ oracle is not in $P/Poly$ if $f(n)$ is superpolynomial.

We know $SUBEXP=\cap_{\epsilon>0}DTIME(2^{n^\epsilon})\not\subseteq DTIME(p(n))$ for any polynomial $p(n)$.

So do we have $SUBEXP^{PP}\not\subseteq P/Poly$? So can we say either $SUBEXP\not\subseteq P/Poly$ or ${PP}\not\subseteq P/Poly$ holds?

I am trying to understand if $C^O\not\subseteq D$ for classes $C,O,D$ then does it follow either $C\not\subseteq D$ or $O\not\subseteq D$?

In other words if we have two classes $C,O$ with $C\subseteq D$ and $O\subseteq D$ then does it mean $C^O\subseteq D$?

Comment: What do you think? Have you tried proving your claim?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I am not very sure. Take $C=P$ and $O=NP$ and clearly $P$ and $NP$ are conjectured to be in $\Sigma_2$ and  $P^{NP}$ is also in $\Sigma_2$. So I do not know what to say on how to approach such problem although seems to be related to lowness of classes.

Comment: P and NP are in $\Sigma_2^P$ *by definition*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $D$ is low for itself ($D^D = D$) then $C,O \subseteq D$ should imply $C^O \subseteq D$, though it might depend on the exact definition of the oracle model (for resource-restricted classes there are sometimes delicate issues there). In contrast, if $D$ isn't low for itself then taking $C=O=D$ we get a counterexample.

Comment: Thank you. Are you saying $P/poly$ is not low for itself? otherwise we will already have an incredible result of either $SUBEXP$ not in $P/poly$ or $PP$ is not in $P/poly$ (meaning either way $PP$ is not in $P/poly$) since we know $SUBEXP^{PP}$ is not in $P/poly$?

Comment: No, I think that P/poly is low for itself, so your result follows.

Comment: isn't $PP$ not in $P/poly$ a new result (this already gives both $PSPACE$ and $NEXP$ not in $P/Poly$) correct? And possibly $\#P$ as well right?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow that part of your argument. If SUBEXP is not in P/poly, why does it follow that PP is not in P/poly?

Comment: I was of the opinion it is already known $SUBEXP$ is in $PP$ (only strict containment is an issue). Am I wrong in this?

Comment: Wikipedia and the Complexity Zoo don't seem to know about it.

Comment: so I am wrong thank you.. so $SUBEXP$ is not in $P/poly$ is the only implication we can get. correct?

Comment: We get exactly what you wrote: either SUBEXP is not in P/poly, or PP is not in P/poly.

Comment: is it also obvious that if SUBEXP is not in P/poly then since $BPP$ is in P/poly would it follow BPP is in SUBEXP (BPP is in PP by definition)?

Comment: You can get many things using logical deduction. There is no need to ask about each and every one of them.

Comment: true but in this case it is not clear as we know  only $BPP\subseteq SUBEXP\cap P/poly \subseteq SUBEXP$ ah thats right $SUBEXP\not\subseteq P/Poly$ will give a language outside $BPP$ but in $SUBEXP$ so that would imply $BPP\subsetneq SUBEXP$ is true.